# If matched then add elements of ArrayList_A to ArrayList , if not then add elements of ArrayList_B to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
package sportsCardsTracker;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test_Mark6 {
    public static ArrayList<String> listingNameList;
    public static ArrayList<String> finalNamesList;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        listingNameList = new ArrayList();
        listingNameList.add("LeBron James 2017-18 Hoops Card");
        listingNameList.add("Stephen Curry Auto Patch, HOT INVESTMENTS!");
        listingNameList.add("Michael Jordan 1998 Jersey Worn Card");

        ArrayList<String> playersNamesList = new ArrayList();
        playersNamesList.add("LeBron James");
        playersNamesList.add("Stephen Curry");
        playersNamesList.add("Michael Jordan");

        finalNamesList = new ArrayList();

        String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(directory + "/src/sportsCardsTracker/CardPrices.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false); //true to not over ride 

        for (int i = 0; i < listingNameList.size(); i++) {
            for (String listingNames : listingNameList) {
                List<String> result = NBARostersScraper_Mark3.getNBARoster().stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
                boolean valueContained = result.stream().anyMatch(s -> listingNames.toLowerCase().matches(".*" + s + ".*"));
                if(valueContained == true) {
                    finalNamesList.add(//The players' name);
                }
            }
            fw.write(String.format("%s, %s\n", finalNamesList.get(i)));
            }

    }
    }
```

Basically, in the `listingsNameList`, I have the listing's names and in the `playersNamesList`, I have all the players' names. What I would like is that, if the code matches the names between the two arrayList and find a player's name, it should returns the players' only.

For example, instead of `"LeBron James 2017-18 Hoops Card"` it should return `"Lebron James"` only. If it does not find anything, then just return the listing's name. So far, I have created a new ArrayList namely `finalNamesList`, my idea would be using an `if` statement (if match found then add players' name to `finalNamesList`, if not add the listing' name to `finalNamesList`). However the code above is not working and it is just adding all of the names in the `listingNameList` to the `finalNamesList`. I suspect that the way I grab the index is wrong - but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to match a pattern that seems wrong. Instead of "match()" you can use string contains method as below.

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (String listingNames : listingNameList) {
    temp = playersNamesList.parallelStream().filter(s -> listingNames.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())).map(s -> s).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    if(temp.size() > 0){
        System.out.println(temp.get(0));
        //fw.write(String.format("%s, %s\n", temp.get(0));
    }
}
```

One more thing, You don't need to use 2 for loop here, with one loop you can achieve your output.
Though You can still optimize this code, I have taken the temp list above that you can avoid.

Comment: Wow! Very cool! I did not notice that. Thank you for your kind help!